# VBA Paste Values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a project that moves many pivot tables from multiple books to one master workbook.  I've got all of the tabs from the source moved into the master book, but now I need to find some code that will break the links between the pivot tables and the source books.  I was thinking a paste special/values function would do the trick but I'm having difficulty getting that to work.  I would also like to note that the VBA macro is located in a different workbook than in the master workbook, so that seems to be complicating things.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is the code I have so far

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Run_Process()

Dim Y As String
Dim M As String
Dim MonthName As String



Y = "2016"
M = "01"
MonthName = "January"

'Opens the workbooks
Workbooks.Open  Filename:="\\(Path)\" & Y & "\" & Y & M & "CD_1993 Source.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\(Path)\" & Y & "\" & Y & M & "CD_1997 Source.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\(Path)\" & Y & "\" & Y & M & "CD_2002 Source.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\(path)\" & Y & "\" & Y & M & "CD_1993 Source2.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\(path)\" & Y & "\" & Y & M & "CD_1997 Source2.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\(path)\" & Y & "\" & Y & M & "CD_2002 Source2.xlsx"


'Adding New Workbook
Workbooks.Add
'Saving the Workbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\(path)\" & Y & "\" & Y & M & "CR_CUNA_Client_Report_Test.xlsx"


'Begin Copying and renaming the tabs from the source workbooks

Workbooks(Y & M & "CD_2002 Source2.xlsx").Sheets("2002").Copy     Before:=Workbooks(Y & M & "CR_CUNA_Client_Report_Test.xlsx").Sheets(1)
Sheets("2002").Name = "2002 Rpt - " & MonthName & " " & Y

Workbooks(Y & M & "CD_2002 Source.xlsx").Sheets("Summ by Pool Year").Copy Before:=Workbooks(Y & M & "CR_CUNA_Client_Report_Test.xlsx").Sheets(1)
Sheets("Summ by Pool Year").Name = "2002 Summ by Pool Year"

Workbooks(Y & M & "CD_1997 Source2.xlsx").Sheets("1997").Copy Before:=Workbooks(Y & M & "CR_CUNA_Client_Report_Test.xlsx").Sheets(1)
Sheets("1997").Name = "1997 Rpt - " & MonthName & " " & Y

Workbooks(Y & M & "CD_1997 Source.xlsx").Sheets("Summ by Pool Year").Copy Before:=Workbooks(Y & M & "CR_CUNA_Client_Report_Test.xlsx").Sheets(1)
Sheets("Summ by Pool Year").Name = "1997 Summ by Pool Year"

Workbooks(Y & M & "CD_1993 Source2.xlsx").Sheets("1993").Copy Before:=Workbooks(Y & M & "CR_CUNA_Client_Report_Test.xlsx").Sheets(1)
Sheets("1993").Name = "1993 Rpt - " & MonthName & " " & Y

Workbooks(Y & M & "CD_1993 Source.xlsx").Sheets("Summ by Pool Year").Copy Before:=Workbooks(Y & M & "CR_CUNA_Client_Report_Test.xlsx").Sheets(1)
Sheets("Summ by Pool Year").Name = "1993 Summ by Pool Year"

Workbooks(Y & M & "CR_CUNA_Client_Report_Test.xlsx").Activate

'Dim Sh As Worksheet
'  For Each Sh In (Format$(Y, "0000") & Format$(M, "00") &     "CR_CUNA_Client_Report_Test.xlsx").Worksheets
'   If Sh.Visible = True Then
'        Sh.Activate
'        Sh.Cells.Copy
'        Sh.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
'
'       Sh.Range("A1").Select
'   End If
' Next Sh
'Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Where CR_CUNA_Client_Report_Test.xlsx is the Master sheet that I'm trying to break the links to the source workbooks in.....

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you paste an example of what your tables look like. Also, provide some of the code you have developed, this way it wont seem like a "request for code" question. Coping Data between two instances of Excel is not difficult so I am sure we can get you sorted quickly.

Comment: Thanks Jeeeped!!  Sorry I asked a question that was already answered - I couldn't find it....but the link to that answer solved my problem!!!